# Why the frame of an SF Symbol isn't encompassing its entire image?

Tags: swiftui

When I put an image on screen, I expect the image to be entirely enclosed in its own frame, but apparently I am wrong. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

My Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                Image(systemName: "envelope.badge.fill")
                Image(systemName: "moon.stars.fill")
            } // Group
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .font(.system(size: 128))
                .border(Color.red)
        } // VStack
            .padding(40)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works as expected in Xcode 12 beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that is now fixed in SwiftUI 2.0 (Xcode 12).

Here is a workaround for SwiftUI 1.0 (Xcode 11).  It uses `UIImage(systemName:)` to get the actual dimensions of the image, and then uses `.aspectRatio(_:contentMode:)` to set the correct aspect ratio.

```
struct SystemImage: View {
    let name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        let uiImage = UIImage(systemName: name)!
        
        return Image(systemName: name)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(uiImage.size, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                SystemImage(name: "envelope.badge.fill")
                SystemImage(name: "moon.stars.fill")
            } // Group
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            .font(.system(size: 128))
            .border(Color.red)
        } // VStack
            .padding(40)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

[image: Image running on iPhone 11 iOS 13.7 simulator]

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the padding before the border.

edit...
Does this help:

```
 HStack {  
    Group {  
        Image(systemName: "envelope.badge.fill")  
        Image(systemName: "moon.stars.fill")  
        } // Group  
            .foregroundColor(.yellow)  
            .font(.system(size: 128))  
            .frame(width:150, height: 150, alignment: .center)  
            .padding(10)  
            .border(Color.red)  
    } // VStack  
        .padding(40)  
        .background(Color.white)
```

[image: Screenshot]